Weight module of $sl(n)$ without maximal vectors?
$V$ is a highest-weight module of $sl(n)$, $W$ is a submodule, then $W$ is a weight module.
For  $ \Lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ and $0\neq v_\Lambda\in V$ satisfying $h(v_\Lambda)=\Lambda(h)v_\Lambda$ for all $h\in\mathfrak{h}$, we say that $v_\Lambda$ is a maximal vector if $x(v_\Lambda)=0$ for all $x\in\mathfrak{n}_+$.
I want to find an example of $W$  without maximal vectors in it.
Is it possible？

I don't believe this is possible. Any submodule will itself be a highest weight module (see here) and highest weight vectors are regular by your definition.
As an aside, I haven't seen "regular" used this way before and would usually use the word "maximal" to mean $\mathfrak{n}_+ \cdot v = 0$ and call a weight vector that is maximal a "highest weight vector".
